# Debugging the second time with breakpoints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When setting breakpoints in haskell code form `ghci`, they only get triggered the first time I do a runthrough of the program.

If I try to run the function again, no breakpoints get triggered.

For example, if I follow the [breakpoint tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html), then calling `main` the second time, does not trigger any breakpoints (i even tried reloading with `:r`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't because you make breakpoints in pure code, and since thunks have already been evaluated, they won't be evaluated again?

Comment: Maybe, but I want to run through the code again. Is that not possible?

Comment: Except for restarting `ghci`, I don't think so...

Comment: @drozzy There is no reason you should want to run the pure code again with the same parameters.  By definition, the debug information will not give you anything different than it gave you the first time.

Comment: @Deestan What if I want to set the breakpoint at an earlier place? So you are saying  that once I run through through debug once, you can't do that.

Comment: @drozzy Ah, of course.  That is a relevant scenario.  Pardon my thick skull. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use :l to load the haskell file a second time, :reload only loads the file if a change is detected.